# Terminal ping and apt not working

Tags: command-line, networking, apt

I have an Ubuntu 18.4 VM running in VM workstation.

I can connect to the internet with Firefox, but when I use the terminal for `apt update` or `apt install` I get the following:

```
$ sudo apt update
Err:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                  
  Could not resolve 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease           
  Could not resolve 'security.ubuntu.com'
Err:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease          
  Could not resolve 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease
  Could not resolve 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'
Reading package lists... Done
```

Also `ping` won't work:

```
ping 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 3063ms
```

I have set my proxy in `/etc/apt/apt.conf` and `~/.bashrc`.

I tried a different DNS, but it still won't work.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please post contents of `/etc/apt/apt.conf` and `~/.bashrc`

Answer (score 2):

My issue was a simple Fix

I am using a laptop and the it was using the WIFI when plugged into the LAN.

must have different rules on the WIFI.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Your network is not configured.  Try the command "ifconfig".  You should see and have a network address that should have been given the computer by a local DHCP daemon on your firewall/modem.

The DHCP server should have also given you a DNS server.  Also try "dig google.com @8.8.8.8" which should give you the IPv4 address of google.com. The @8.8.8.8 tells dig to use Google's DNS server for queries. If the dig command does give you the IPv4 address back see if you can "ping 172.217.12.14",  The 172.217.... address is the address of my google.com.

Is your firewall on and blocking icmp packets?  If it is on you should stop the firewall (temporarily) as it can also give this error.  Type in "dmesg" command and see if the google.com address is being blocked (this assumes that the firewall is writing the blocked address(es) to /var/log/syslog).

Comment: if firefox works, then some network works.  most likely it only has IP access to a local private subnet and it is using a proxy server on that network.